# React-native load to android device permission denied

Tags: android, react-native

My app works fine on my desktop simulator so now I am trying to load it into my android phone.

I have gone into dev options and put in my ip address:8081 but now the error in my terminal is access denied.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: Have you enabled USB debugging on your device? If so, do you see your device when you run `adb devices` in Terminal? [Docs for more info](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-android.html#content).

Comment: Yes I go USB debugging on and when i run adb devices it does come up

Comment: I got the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer was that my device was not on the same wifi as my computer.  Pretty simple answer but was very frustrating, hope it helps someone else.